# Clarification of a specific method

Tags: oop

On my homework I have a question/part where I am confused at (can't understand it).

*Iv ) The main method calls the printdata() method for each Earthquake object. The printData() method accepts an Earthquake object as a parameter and prints all the Earthquake's idea, including latitude, longitude, magnitude and classification.* **Remember that you will need to call the determineClassification() method for the Earthquake object before calling the accessor method and printing the classification.**

I understood everything up till the bolded era, what does it mean when it says call the determine method for earthquake object before calling accessor method and printing it.

Part I: earthquake service class has 4 attributes, lat, lon, mag, classification

include following for part I, constructor, second constructor with parameter (lat, lon, mag), accessor for method for each attribute, mutator method for all attributes EXCEPT for classification.

A method named determineclassification() that uses range checking, based on the table shown above and the value of the magnitude attribute, and sets the value of the classification attribute to the appropriate word specified in the table. Remember to choose either low end or high end range checking when designing this method.

Part II italicized.

PSEUDO CODE.

Earthquake service class

```
public class Earthquakes

     // declarations
    private num latitude
    private num longitude 
    private num magnitude
    private String classification

    public Earthquakes ( )
        latitude = 0.0
        longitude = 0.0
        magnitude = 0.0
        classification = “new”
    return

    public  void Earthquake(num lat, num lon, num mag)
        latitude = lat
        longitude = lon
        major = maj
    return

    public num getLatitude( ) 
    return latitude

    public num getLongitude ( ) 
    return longitude

    public String getMagnitude( )  
    return magnitude

    public num getClassification( ) 
    return classification

    public void setLatitude (num lat) 
        latitude = lat
    return

    public void setLongitude (num lon) 
        longitude = lon
    return

    public void setMagnitude(num mag) 
        magnitude = mag
    return


Public determination class ()
If magnitude > 0 AND magnitude < 2.9 then
    Classification = Micro
Else if magnitude > 3 AND magnitude < 3.9 then
    Classification = Minor
Else if magnitude 4 > AND magnitude < 4.9 then
    Classification = Light
Else  if magnitude 5 > AND magnitude < 5.9 then
    Classification = Moderate
Elseif magnitude 6 > AND magnitude < 6.9 then
    Classification = Strong
Else if magnitude 7 > AND magnitude < 7.9 then
    Classification = Major
Else if magnitude >= 8
    Clarification = Great
end if

end class

HazardsProgram class

Public class HazardsProgram

Public void main ()
// Declarations

Earthquake1 (lat 47.74N, lon 154.34E, mag 5.1)

Earthquake2 (lat 35.44N, lon 97.46W, mag 2.8)

Earthquake3 (lat 29.73S, lon 177.98W, mag 6.5)

Earthquake4 (lat 61.04N, long 147.73W, mag 9.2)

Print Data void eq(earthquake1)
    Output latitude, longitude, magnitude, classification

Return

End class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach earthquake as e
   e.determineClassification(this)
   e.printdata(this)

function determineClassification(e)
   e.class = class1

function printdata(e)
   e.print()
```

Comment: hmm still a bit confused. my determine classification () is set up like that, and inside it they have if then else statements (on magnitude and classification). So is it referring to determineclassification(earthquake), set determineclassification, or call a print method for determineclassification.

Comment: i think all it is saying is that you need to call the determineClassification method on the earthquake object before you print it, although usually 'accessor' methods get information about an object(something like getPrintData()).

Comment: I understand printing it, but still not sure what to do with the determine method, determineclassification (earthquake1, 2, 3, 4) printdata void eq(Earthquake1). I am sorry if I am making it more complicating, but really I am only stuck in this one particular area.

Comment: are you looking for help with the logic inside determineClassification?  It may help if you post your code.

Comment: alright updated my question again, hope it clears things up from my end.

Comment: ok, in your main function at the end, you need to call dertermineClassification right before you print.

Comment: so would that go right after all the earthquake methods and before the print method and if so what do I put in the class method. Would it be determineclassification (earthquake1, earthquake2, earthquake3, earthquake4) and then below it earthquake1 to set up a call.

Comment: yes. and in the method you either return the classification or set the classification for each earthquake.

Comment: so it would be one of two ways determineclassification (methods inside) return, OR same thing except earthquake1 (lat, lon, mag) and vice versa underneath the determineclassification () am I correct.